How to get stable mount points for SMB network shares on macOS?
I have multiple users on my MacBook, e.g. for different family members, or also for certain roles. These users frequently access data on a fileserver that provides access to that data via SMB.
When a user connects to an SMB network share that share is mounted under /Volumes. Let's assume there is an SMB network share named data.

The first user that mounts the share (user A) gets the mount point /Volumes/data.
The second user that mounts the share (user B) gets the mount point /Volumes/data-1.
The third user that mounts the share (user C) gets the mount point /Volumes/data-2.
etc.

The next time the system is rebooted and users are logging in in a different order they will not get the same mount points that they had previously. For instance, if user C is now the first user to mount the share, they will now get the mount point /Volumes/data. This can be experienced even without a reboot, simply when users log out and then log back in at a later time.
In the Finder the numeric suffixes are hidden, but many other applications are using the actual filesystem path somewhere under the hood, and things are breaking by the constantly changing paths. One of the simplest examples is the list of "Recently opened" files that many applications have - when a user logs in the next time they may not be able to use this list to quickly access the same file they were working on just a short while ago.
So my question is: Is it possible to somehow configure macOS to have user-specific stable mount points that do not change based on the order in which users are mounting network shares? Something like /Volumes/<username>/data or /Users/<username>/Volumes/data.

Try to mount the share as root, using this formulation.
